# Change Text in Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

Is there a way to change the text displayed in the bootstrap typeahead, such that if I have a list of values for the source ["Smith", "Allen"], in the typeahead drop-down, I can display ["Dr. Allen", "Dr. Smith"]?

Edit: The prefix may change (based on some other input or the current input) so its not practical to reinitialize each time. I ended up hardcoding the HTML in the highlight component of typeahead. If anyone has any better suggestions, I'd be glad to here it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have as source  ["Smith", "Allen"] and you'd like in the drop down 'Dr. Allen', 'Dr. Smith'] you can do:

```
var values=['Smith','Allen']; 
    var prefix = $('.myInput').val();
$('.typeahead').typeahead({source: function() { 
    var returnArray=[]; 
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){ 
    returnArray.push(prefix + values[i])  
    } 
    return returnArray;
})
```

Comment: I should have been more explicit, the prefix component may change, so I want to avoid reinitializing the source each time.

Comment: Can you pass it as parameter or variable? I edited the example adding a prefix. You can get the prefix from another input, and hidden input, or whatever you prefer, depends on what you are working on.